I was trying to update the height constraint of my view during an animation. Its not getting updated why..?
Here is how i have configured the profile view,
-(void)addProfileView
{
    if(!_profileView)
    {
        _profileView = [ProfileView new];
        _profileView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        _profileView.delegate=self;
        _profileView.alpha = 1.0;
        _profileView.opaque = YES;
        _profileView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        [self.view addSubview:_profileView];
        NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_profileView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0 constant:160];
        NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_profileView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0];
        NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_profileView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:0];
        NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_profileView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:-64];
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[heightConstraint, widthConstraint, leftConstraint, topConstraint]];
    }
}

Now, why is the profile view's height not changing after the animation? Should I add the constraints to the superview? What's the difference between adding constraints directly to the superview and using [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[]] ?
-(void)animateProfileViewBasedOnOffset:(BOOL)isTop
{
__block NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
    
    for (NSLayoutConstraint * constraint in [_profileView constraints]) {
        if (constraint.firstAnchor == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
            heightConstraint = constraint;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        if (isTop) {
            heightConstraint.constant = 64;
        }
        else {
            heightConstraint.constant = 160;
        }
        [_profileView layoutIfNeeded];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }completion:^(BOOL completion)
     {
         NULL;
     }];
}

The height of the profileView only changes when I add its constraint to the superview ([self.view addConstraints:@[]]). During the animation, I loop through all the constraints of the superview to find the specific constraint and update it.

Stick to activateConstraints: it knows better than you do what to add each constraint to. Instead of hunting for the height constraint at animation time, just keep a reference to it at the time you create it.

During an animation you should use the presentationLayer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953459/get-current-frame-of-uiview-while-animated but I don't suggest to keep a reference to the constraint instead...

It would also be useful to know when all this is happening. I could incorporate your code pretty much as is into a demo project where I tap a button in the interface and alternate with animation between a 64 height and a 160 height, and your code pretty much as is would work. Therefore in order to know why your code is not working we might need to know more about other aspects of the environment in which all this is happening.

You should check and confirm that you are, in fact, finding the Height constraint:
for (NSLayoutConstraint * constraint in [_profileView constraints]) {
    if (constraint.firstAnchor == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
        heightConstraint = constraint;
        break;
    }
}
if (heightConstraint) {
    NSLog(@"Found Height Constraint: %@", heightConstraint);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Did NOT find Height Constraint!");
}

That code (in my quick test) does NOT find the Height constraint, so of course, no animation.
This code:
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in _profileView.constraints) {
    // Check if the constraint is a height constraint
    if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight && constraint.firstItem == _profileView) {
        // Found the height constraint
        heightConstraint = constraint;
        break;
    }
}
if (heightConstraint) {
    NSLog(@"Found Height Constraint: %@", heightConstraint);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Did NOT find Height Constraint!");
}

Does find the Height constraint, and the animation happens as expected.

As a side note, you might want to look at the more modern way of setting up constraints. This matches your constraints, but I think you'd agree it is much more readable (and much easier to edit when needed):
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [_profileView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:160.0],
    [_profileView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor],
    [_profileView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor],
    [_profileView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor constant:-64.0],
]];


Edit
As mentioned in comments by Matt, you are (almost always) better off adding a constraint property that you can update when desired.
Here's an example of that approach:
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AnimSubViewController : UIViewController
@end

@interface AnimSubViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *profileView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
@end

@implementation AnimSubViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackgroundColor;
    
    [self addProfileView];
}

-(void)addProfileView
{
    if(!_profileView)
    {
        //_profileView = [ProfileView new];
        _profileView = [UIView new];
        _profileView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
        _profileView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        //_profileView.delegate=self;
        _profileView.alpha = 1.0;
        _profileView.opaque = YES;
        _profileView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        [self.view addSubview:_profileView];

        // set the _heightConstraint property, so we can modify its .constant later
        _heightConstraint = [_profileView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:160.0];
        
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
            //[_profileView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:160.0],
            _heightConstraint,
            [_profileView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor],
            [_profileView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor],
            [_profileView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor constant:-64.0],
        ]];

    }
}

-(void)animateProfileViewBasedOnOffset:(BOOL)isTop
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        if (isTop) {
            self->_heightConstraint.constant = 64;
        }
        else {
            self->_heightConstraint.constant = 160;
        }
        // not needed
        //[self->_profileView layoutIfNeeded];
        
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        
    } completion:^(BOOL completion) {
        NULL;
    }];
    
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // hide/show _profileView on tap anywhere
    [self animateProfileViewBasedOnOffset:_heightConstraint.constant == 160.0];
}

@end


I would urge the OP not to listen to this, but rather to do what I suggested in my comment, "Instead of hunting for the height constraint at animation time, just keep a reference to it at the time you create it." Constraint-hunting is a bad technique, even if you can get it to work. It's an anti-pattern. We know in advance that we're going to want to modify the constraint on this one constraint; therefore the correct pattern is to maintain a reference to it.

@matt - I agree, "hunting for constraints" is a bad technique... although I wanted to explain the OP's error. Added an Edit to my answer with the "maintain a reference" approach.
